# creating responsive div containers equal in size, with different sized uploaded images fill entire div.

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

this might sound confusing, but basically I have a section on my website called classifieds that I'm designing that I want to look uniform, regardless of the type of image uploaded.

it will be something like

```
<div class = "classified-container>
    <img class = "classified-img" src = "blablabla.jpg "/>
</div>
```

I am basically trying to get it to look like reddit, where all the boxes are the same size but the images aren't necessarily but they still fill the entire div and aren't warped/stretched. At the same time I want it to be responsive too and look good on mobile. I've tried setting the img to be max width = 100% and max height = 100% but it isn't working quite right, some images aren't filling out the entire div container.

What is the best approach to doing this that is also compatible in most browsers using css?

Answer (score 0):

```
 .classified-container{
   background-image:url('blablabla.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

and your HTML :

```
<div class ="classified-container></div>
```

Comment: sorry I should've clarified this, but the whole page of the site is setup using php to implement and create the page layout, so a solution where the image isn't set as a background image would be better for me.

Answer (score 0):

would this be kind of the desired output ? (demo below):

```
.classified-container {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 15vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.classified-img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.classified-container {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 15vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.classified-img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin:0;
```

```html
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/160" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/110/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/90/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/160" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/110/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/90/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/160" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/110/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/90/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" />
</div>
<div class="classified-container">
  <img class="classified-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS `object-fit: cover;` can take care of this. It behaves similar to `background-size:cover;` and fills the container while preserving the image aspect ratio. [Checkout this awesome explanation](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/).

So following code will fills up the containers with their images while keeping the image aspect ratio. Now if you really want to get creative try combining with `object-position:` attribute.

```
div {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 15vw;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;     /* assures img height to be container height */
  min-height: 100%;        
  width: 100%;          /* limit the overflow */
  object-fit: cover;    /* fills the parent w/o stretching */
}
```

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyaVba?editors=1100)

Pretty good browser support too (*[object-fit is supported by everything except IE/Edge.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)*)

Comment: "everything except IE/Edge" is _not_ good support. The web is for everyone.

Comment: True that. Since max,min & width acts as fallbacks it still works OK on IE/Edge ( with a stretched effect where image ratio is weird.) Since he  can't use the `background-image` option, I thought this would be the next best thing.

Comment: He _can_ use `background-image`, by applying it as a style attribute on the DOM element. It's exactly as much work as programmatically applying a `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover` will do the trick.

```
<div class ="classified-container" style="background-image: url('blablabla.jpg')"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .classified-container {
    background-size: cover;
  }
</style>
```

background-image *actually* has good support: back to IE9, and all other browsers.

You have to add the background-image style to each element, with the path to the image inside `url("`{path}`")`.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp